# Using argument variables in an alias

Tags: bash, scripting, alias

Using Cygwin on Windows 10.
In ~/.bashrc, I write:

```
test=hola
alias add_hello="echo $1; echo hello"
alias add_hello2="echo $test; echo hello"
```

which, when both are run, results in:

```
$add_hello hola
hello hola
$add_hello2
hola hello
```

Why would these be run in different order? I have tried unaliasing them and simply redefining them without using .bashrc but the issue is the same. Also, writing a script called "add_hello":

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1; echo hello
```

will  work:

```
$./add_hello hola
hola 
hello
```

Comment: Not able to get you. Can u pls elaborate more ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect `$1` to be when you call it from bashrc, Your `$1` is never printed because you mentioned that in an alias but not setting it. As its empty , echo is not printing it.(`echo "'<nothing here> hello' aa"`)

```
-->alias add_hello="echo hello"
-->add_hello aa       #< this is same as echo "'hello' aa"
-->hello aa
```

Better you should try bash function in bashrc file:

```
add_hello()
{
echo 'hello'
echo "$1"
}
```

Comment: Oh I see now. I was expecting it to act like a script where $1 would refer to an "argument" to the alias but I see it doesn't work the same way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your first test `add_hello hola` result in

```
echo $1; echo hello holla
```